# Redux vs. HOC Pattern with useContext() and useReducer()

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why would you use the external Redux library over React's own [useContext()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) and [useReducer()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hooks, with the [Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) pattern?

Installing and importing an additional, large library such as Redux increases the size of your application and consumes more resources. Redux is essentially using the HOC pattern, takes advantage of the JavaScript reducer pattern, and uses a "context" to keep tack of global state.

React HOCs take care the tree hell issue created by context providers, in large apps:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider1>
      <Provider2>
        <Provider3>
          <Layout>
            <Main />
          </Layout>
        </Provider3>
      </Provider2>
    </Provider1>
  )
}
```

I've tried to do research on the differences and pros/cons, but haven't come to a conclusion. The only major advantage I see with using Redux is that it has its own browser extension, [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en), that's helpful for debugging and inspecting global state and HOCs. In your opinion, which is better to use and why? Redux, or React `useContext()` and `useReducer()` (with HOCs and [useMemo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo))?

Comment: Recommendations for libraries (or not) are explicitly off topic here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where should this question be posted? I'm not asking for recommendations on libraries, but rather the advantage/disadvantage of each method.

Comment: I don't think there's an SE site where this would be on topic, opinion-based content generally isn't, but there's lots of other internet.

Comment: Redux / React Redux was around before `useReducer` was a thing. `useReducer` was created due to the popularity of flux based state management. Redux is a single store (may or may not be better depending on the situation) and supports middleware to allow for easy side effects, testing, action validation, action cancelling, etc. Everyone has different requirements and preferences.

Answer (score 4):

Redux uses context, but not for state value propagation, but just to pass the never-changing store reference down. As such, Redux' context will never cause any rerender. After that, subscriptions to store changes are used with selectors and the `useSyncExternalStore` hook.

By just using `useReducer` and `useContext`, you cannot recreate a performant state management library, as any update to any part of the value passed through the context will rerender all consumers. You can get around that by using many contexts, but ends as soon as you have dynamically added properties or a dynamic number of values you want to propagate performantly.

In short: use a state mgmt library. It doesn't need to be Redux, you can also look into other libraries as MobX, Recoil, XState, Jotai, Zustand, Valtio, HookState or others - but Context is not suited to actually manage state. It's just a mechanism to propagate a single value that rarely changes to a few consumers.

You can read more on this in [Why React Context is Not a "State Management" Tool (and Why It Doesn't Replace Redux)](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2021/01/context-redux-differences/).